# Merging two data frames not getting Key Column on both dataframes with Full OuterJoin

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outer-join

I have two dataframes like below. I using pandas and numpy to compare differences.

```
df_a
               Key                           Value
0       data_owner                            John
1     locationcode                           local
2             Unit                           sales
3      application                       autosales


df_b 
               Key                           Value
0       data_owner                            John
1     locationcode                           local
2             Unit                           sales
3      application                       autosales
4       department                     frontoffice
```

I am using below code for merging

```
 df = pd.merge(df_a,df_b,on=['Key'],how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)

 df['diff'] = np.where((df['Value_x']==df['Value_y']), 'No', 'Yes')
```

My intention to output compare both df and any missing items on both side should come to output.

Actual output below: but problem is i want to display Key from both dataframes, but if you see below output its showing only once, i.e i need Key_y also to be part of output.

```
              Key                         Value_x                          Value_y   diff
0       data_owner                            John                            John   No
1     locationcode                           local                           local   No
2             unit                           sales                           sales   No
3      application                       autosales                       autosales   No
4       department                     frontoffice                             NaN   No
```

Expected output: I wanted to display Key from both

```
            Key_x                          Value_x       Key_y                    Value_y    diff
0       data_owner                            John       data_owner                  John    No
1     locationcode                           local       locationcode               local    No
2             unit                           sales       unit                       sales    No
3      application                       autosales       application            autosales    No
4       department                     frontoffice       NaN                          NaN    Yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) to add the suffixes to the columns of both the dataframes before merging them, this way their keys will not combined into single column after merging:

```
df = pd.merge(
    df_b.add_suffix('_x'), df_a.add_suffix('_y'), 
    left_on='Key_x', right_on='Key_y', how='outer')

df['diff'] = np.where(df['Value_x'].eq(df['Value_y']), 'No', 'Yes')
```

---

```
# print(df)
          Key_x      Value_x         Key_y    Value_y diff
0    data_owner         John    data_owner       John   No
1  locationcode        local  locationcode      local   No
2          Unit        sales          Unit      sales   No
3   application    autosales   application  autosales   No
4    department  frontoffice           NaN        NaN  Yes
```

Comment: it works like charm. thank you.. one more doubt how to get "Not Applicable" instead of Nan.

Comment: simply use `df = df.fillna('Not Applicable')`.